# SDL2_ttfを使用したフォントの読み込みで失敗

Tags: c++

最終的にSDL2_ttfを使用してOpenGLのテクスチャとして読み込ませたいと考えてます。
まずSDL2_ttf単体でフォントの読み込みのテストを行いました。

下記のコードは正常に実行できますが、毎回フォントデータを読み込みに行ってしまうため速度が出ません。

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    TTF_Init();
    while( true ){
        SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_RWFromFile( "font.ttf", "rb" );
        TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFontRW( rwops, 0, 14 );
        SDL_Surface *texture = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended( font, "test", [](){
            SDL_Color c= { 255,255,255,255 };
            return c;
        }());
        cout << TTF_GetError() << endl;
        TTF_CloseFont( font );
        SDL_RWclose( rwops );
        SDL_Delay( 100 );
    }
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

そこでrwopsに読み込む処理をループの外に置いたところ、TTF_RenderUTF8_Blendedでブレークし、以下のエラーが出力されました。

> 0x71002A85 (SDL2_ttf.dll) で例外がスローされました (SDL_Test.exe 内): 0xC0000005:
>   場所 0x00000000 の読み取り中にアクセス違反が発生しました

TTF_GetError()からは"Couldn't load font file"と出力されました。

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_RWFromFile( "font.ttf", "rb" );
    while( true ){
        TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFontRW( rwops, 0, 14 );
        cout << TTF_GetError() << endl;
        SDL_Surface *texture = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended( font, "test", [](){
            SDL_Color c= { 255,255,255,255 };
            return c;
        }());
        TTF_CloseFont( font );
        SDL_Delay( 100 );
    }
    SDL_RWclose( rwops );
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

おそらくどこかでrwopsがクリアされたと考えていますが何処だかわからず・・・
分かる方いたらご教授お願いします。

開発環境はVisualStudio2015です。
フォントデータは読み込めるディレクトリに配置しています。

SDL2リファレンス
http://sdl2referencejp.osdn.jp/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

オフィシャルではありませんが，githubにあるSDL_ttfのミラーリポジトリを見てみると，`TTF_CloseFont`が内部で`SDL_RWclose`を呼び出しているようです．
https://github.com/ErintLabs/SDL_ttf/blob/a9fbd1912c9a8015ce4bcc2a4ac93be745c563a2/SDL_ttf.c#L933

質問とは関係ないですが，`font`も外に出してしまうのはどうでしょうか？
いちいち何度も開いては閉じるのは効率が悪そうです．

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_RWFromFile( "font.ttf", "rb" );
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFontRW( rwops, 0, 14 );
    while( true ){
        cout << TTF_GetError() << endl;
        SDL_Surface *texture = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended( font, "test", [](){
            SDL_Color c= { 255,255,255,255 };
            return c;
        }());

        SDL_Delay( 100 );
    }
    TTF_CloseFont( font );
    //SDL_RWclose( rwops );
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```